# Print preview trims data on edge/chrome in Portrait mode

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, portrait

`Print preview` is cutting off right edges/side(few columns to be specific) of an HTML report in our Java based web-app in `Chrome/Edge` starting version `117` in `Portrait` mode, it does work in `Landscape` mode though. In `Firefox`, both mode works just fine without any cutting off. How to fix it?

I am aware Chrome/Edge uses same js engine compared to FF and hence the problem.
Is there a CSS or some other fix for this issue? Any tips are greatly appreciated.

The element uses `absolute position`. It was working prior to `version 117`.

Debug Steps:

```
 Load the page 
 Open a report(created using HTML table). 
 Right mouse click > Print on Edge/Chrome
 Portrait mode - report is clipped off on right side
 Landscape mode - report rendered as desired
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I found out a solution, happened to be the scale setting on the print options page. Chrome/Edge seems to be use bigger font size by default. Once I modified the scale ratio to a lower value from 100%, it seems to fit in the page as desired.